# ASP.NET session is working on all browser but not on latest Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox

Remove() on logout button, and whenever I go back to the page it logouts and redirects to home properly, but on Firefox, after you click the back button the user is still logged in but whenever you refresh the page it logs out automatically.

Any idea how to fix this on Firefox browser?

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Comment: @viveknuna no errors on console

Comment: Put you logout code and how it redirects to Home page?

Comment: Session.Remove();
Redirect (aspx).

works fine on google chrome, but does not work on firefox, you need to refresh then it will redirect to home